# A uniformly convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, uniform-convergence

How does one show that the series
$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \left\{\frac{s}{k} - \log\left(1 + \frac{s}{k}\right)\right\}, \quad s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, -1, -2, \ldots\}$$
is uniformly convergent? Here, $\log z$ is the principal value of the logarithm (with the branch cut along the negative real axis).

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: It has been pointed out in the comments that this series is only locally uniformly convergent.

Comment: The series is not uniformly convergent. Every term is unbounded (look at $\operatorname{Re} s \to +\infty$). It is, however, locally uniformly convergent.

Comment: @DanielFischer If it is only locally uniformly convergent can it be differentiated termwise?

Comment: Yes. Differentiating is a local operation.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. Will the resulting series hold for all $s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, -1, -2, \ldots\}$?

Comment: We have no problem at $0$, by the way, but we have a problem on all of $(-\infty,-1]$, since that gets us into the branch cut of the logarithm. It will be okay for all $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,-1]$, and the derivative can be extended holomorphically to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ -k : k\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$, but the series itself cannot.

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually, the function is $\log \Gamma(s) + \gamma s + \log s$, so that is why I excluded $\{0, -1, -2, \ldots\}$. I am trying to understand why the digamma function is defined for all $s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, -1, -2, \ldots\}$.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\log f(s)\right) = \frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}$$ wherever $\log f(s)$ is defined and holomorphic. But of course the logarithmic derivative $\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}$ does not need to care about any branch cuts of the logarithm, that is happy wherever $f$ is holomorphic and nonzero.